# WPF binding update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Can anyone explain why I cannot use **new** to reset the binding data?

Using MVVM, the Data is binding to a ListBox.

The DataList already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

In the method OnChange()

```
public void OnChange()
{
    data = new ObservableCollection<DataList>(); // not work
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 1" });
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 2" });
}
```

but

```
public void OnChange()
{
    data.Clear(); // works fine
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 1" });
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 2" });
}
```

The ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<DataList> data;
public ObservableCollection<DataList> Data
{
    get { return data; }
    set { data = value; }
}

public ViewModel()
{
    this.Command_OnChange = new RelayCommand(ExecuteCommand1, CanExecuteCommand);

    data = new ObservableCollection<DataList>();
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Default 1" });
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Default 2" });
}

public void OnChange()
{
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 1" });
    data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 2" });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you change the backing field, there is no way that wpf could know about the change.

In fact you can overwrite the variable with new instance of `ObservableCollection`, but you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `ViewModel` class too.

```
private ObservableCollection<DataList> data;
public ObservableCollection<DataList> Data
{
    get { return data; }
    set 
    { 
        data = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Data");
    }
}
```

And in your OnChange method

```
public void OnChange()
{
    Data = new ObservableCollection<DataList>();//Note the use of Data property not field
    Data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 1" });
    Data.Add(new DataList() { Text = "Changed 2" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can see by modifying Data directly, it triggers the set and issue property change to View. Is it OK to use "Data", not "data" in OnChange() method?

Comment: @aicu. To be honest, there is no reason to create new `ObservableCollection` there; simply using `data.Clear` is enough. If at all you want to do, then you have to notify the change using `OnPropertyChanged()`. But, using `Data` property is fine there. There is nothing wrong.